# Change button style with VisualStateManager

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, uwp, blend

I am working on a Universal Windows App.

I want to change the Style of my button under different states but I cant figure out (I'm new to this)

Here is my visual state group

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="StartStopTimer">
    <VisualState x:Name="Start">
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="Stop">
        <VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState.Setters>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

I have two styles setup called `StartButtonStyle` and `StopButtonStyle`.

So I want to change the buttons style to `StopButonStyle` in the `Stop` visual state and `StartButtonStyle` in the `Start` visual state.

How do I do this?  I tried with record on in *Expression Blend* but it doesn't apply anything to my visual state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="StartStopTimer">
            <VisualState x:Name="Start">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TestButton"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource StartButtonStyle}">
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Stop">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TestButton"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{StaticResource StopButtonStyle}">
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Of course you need to have defined your styles in the resources, for example in page resources.

Please don't forget to mark my reply as an answer.